# Nodejs 14.5 Filesystem API what is the Dirent "Symbol(type)" property?

Tags: node.js, file, directory, filesystems, readdir

I am doing some basic readdir operations and file/directory read operations with Node 14.5 and filesystem api...

I am just wondering, as I get an "Dirent" object that describes a file/directory, when I iterate through the properties of it , I can see a "[Symbol(type)]" property with a number value, thats probably the type of that file.. however I cannot access that property in any way...

```
Dirent {
  name: 'Some name of file.mp4',
  [Symbol(type)]: 1
}
```

My  question now is:  what is that kind of property and how could I access it? Or how can I create such a property and why does is even show up? I know I can usee methods like isDirectory() etc. but I was just interested to know what that property is...

here is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const walkDirs = async (dir_path, isSubdir = false, round = 0) => {
  try {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(dir_path);
    const dirs = fs.opendirSync(dir_path);
    // console.log(dirs);
    for await (const dirent of dirs) {
      for ( let prop in dirent) {
        console.log("prop:", prop,  dirent[prop]);
      }
    }

  } catch(error) {
    console.log("Error catched: ", error);
  }
}

walkDirs("D:/", false, 0);
```

Comment: This might help https://javascript.info/symbol

Comment: Symbols are typically used as property names for one of two reasons: 1) when you need a property name that absolutely cannot conflict with anything else and 2) when you want some privacy of access (more formally designating a property as private - though you can still jump through hoops to get the value if you really want it).  My guess here would be the privacy aspect.  This is likely some data that is used by Dirent methods, but the data is not meant to be publicly documented or used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the [fs module's source code for the `DirEnt` class](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/utils.js#L118), you find this:

```
class Dirent {
  constructor(name, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this[kType] = type;
  }

  isDirectory() {
    return this[kType] === UV_DIRENT_DIR;
  }

  isFile() {
    return this[kType] === UV_DIRENT_FILE;
  }

  isBlockDevice() {
    return this[kType] === UV_DIRENT_BLOCK;
  }

  isCharacterDevice() {
    return this[kType] === UV_DIRENT_CHAR;
  }

  isSymbolicLink() {
    return this[kType] === UV_DIRENT_LINK;
  }

  isFIFO() {
    return this[kType] === UV_DIRENT_FIFO;
  }

  isSocket() {
    return this[kType] === UV_DIRENT_SOCKET;
  }
}
```

If you then look for `kType`, you find this:

```
const kType = Symbol('type');
```

And, all the values in that code such as `UV_DIRECT_DIR` and `UV_DIRENT_FILE` are constants imported from libuv that describe the type of directory entry.

So, it appears that the property you are asking about contains the libuv type for the directory entry and they are using a Symbol as the property name because they do not intend for that internal implementation detail to be used publicly or documented.

If you don't know what libuv is, it's the cross platform library that nodejs uses to access OS services.  It abstracts some operating system details into a common interface to allow more nodejs code to be written once and work on multiple platforms (Win/Mac/Unix).

---

The underlying UV constants mentioned above are defined [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3abb52fdb683c9c9ade1b2c7d16d0f640bbaacfd/deps/uv/include/uv.h#L1130) in C++ code in libuv in `uv.h`.

```
typedef enum {
  UV_DIRENT_UNKNOWN,
  UV_DIRENT_FILE,
  UV_DIRENT_DIR,
  UV_DIRENT_LINK,
  UV_DIRENT_FIFO,
  UV_DIRENT_SOCKET,
  UV_DIRENT_CHAR,
  UV_DIRENT_BLOCK
} uv_dirent_type_t;
```

Comment: How access the `Symbol(type)`?
If the Dirents are in the array `directory` I can't access it with `directory[directoryIndex]["Symbol(type)"]`.

Comment: @Inherent - Please ask your own question, show your own code and describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @jfriend00 - "My question now is: what is that kind of property and how could I access it?"

Comment: @Inherent, try: `const type = file[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(file)[0]]`

Comment: @f1lt3r - Please don't try to answer these kinds of "new questions in a comment".  If inherent wanted to ask their own question, they should do so in their own question, not here in comments.  And, you shouldn't be trying to answering these here either.  FYI, the intent of the way `kType` is designed is to keep it private.  While you may be able to sleuth it indirectly using other means, that is unsupported and could change at any time.  In other words, it's not a good way to write production code. That's why I asked them to write their own question where they could explain the actual problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 - But his own question *DOES* ask how to access it.

Comment: @f1lt3r - inherent has not posted a new stackoverflow question of their own here, only written some comments.  Comments are NOT for new, original questions.  They should write their own NEW question where their context can be shown and answers can be supplied.

Comment: What do the words "how could I access it?" mean to you?

Comment: @f1lt3r - This will be my last response to you here as this is not what comments are for on stackoverflow.  My use of the term "question" here means a top level, original question here on stackoverflow, not some phrasing formed into a question in a comment.  You should not be asking new, original questions in a comment.  You should be posting your own top level question and describing your own situation.

Comment: I don't have a question. The question "How could I access it?" was asked by the OP in his question at the top. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62837749/2816869 - Why would I open a new question if the OP has already asked it? You appear to be saying the OP did not ask that question. But I can see that he has asked it, and I have provided the information he requested. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78164339/2816869

Comment: @f1lt3r - As explained in my answer, you cannot access those constants.  They are privately defined in libuv and not made public to Javascript.  You will notice that the OP accepted my answer and did not ask any further followup questions likely because that part of the OP's question is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a files' numerical ENUM value with the following line of code:

```js
const num = file[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(file)[0]]
```

This code snippet demonstrates how you can read a directory using `withFileTypes` symbols, and return an object with the files and directories split into their own arrays - split by ENUM value.

```js
const readTypes = {
    1: "file",
    2: "dir",
    3: "link"
}

const readDir = (dir) => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => { 
        if (err) return reject(console.error(err)); 

        const result = {
            root: path.resolve(dir),
            file: [],
            dir: []
        };

        for (const file of files) { 
            const num = file[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(file)[0]]
            const validEnum = Object.keys(readTypes).includes(String(num));
            if (!validEnum) continue

            const type = readTypes[num];
            result[type].push(path.resolve(dir, file.name))
        }

        resolve(result)
    })
});

readDir('./').then(console.log)
```

The output will look something like this:

```bash
{
  root: '/home/user/repos/create-react-app',
  file: [
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.alexignore',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.alexrc',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.eslintignore',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.eslintrc.json',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.gitattributes',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.gitignore',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.prettierignore',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.prettierrc',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/CHANGELOG-0.x.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/CHANGELOG-1.x.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/CHANGELOG-2.x.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/CHANGELOG-3.x.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/CHANGELOG-4.x.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/CHANGELOG.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/CONTRIBUTING.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/LICENSE',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/README.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/SECURITY.md',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/lerna.json',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/netlify.toml',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/package-lock.json',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/package.json',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/screencast-error.svg',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/screencast.svg',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/test.mjs'
  ],
  dir: [
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.git',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/.github',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/docusaurus',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/packages',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/tasks',
    '/home/user/repos/create-react-app/test'
  ]
}
```

I hope this helps you answer your question, "How could I access it?"

Note: Rather than using the underlying ENUM, it is better to use `file.isFile()` and `file.isDir()` and so on... as the ENUM may be subject to change, where as `isFile()`, `isDir()` should remain the same over time.